# Error in temp.tc[i] replacement has length zero

Tags: r

I have no experience with coding so please excuse any mistakes I may make in trying to explain this problem. I have code written for R that is supposed to return some curves. The code reads a csv file as an input.

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in temp.tc[i] <- (as.numeric(unique(unlist(regmatches(dur, temp))))) :
```

replacement has length zero

It looks like this is the part of the code that is giving me the error:

```
for(i in seq (1,rl,1))
{
dur <- ddf[[c]][i] #steps through each cell in the duration column
dur1 <- toString(dur)  #converts the cell into a string
dur2 <- unlist(strsplit(dur1, split="")) #splits the string into individual characters
dur3 <- strtoi(dur2[1]) #converts the characters back into integers

#If a value is found, proceed through if statements to identify key words 
if(is.na(dur3)== FALSE)
{
temp <- gregexpr("[0‐9]+", dur)  #removes strings from duration

#checks if duration has units of minutes 
if(grepl(min, dur) == TRUE)
{
  #removes words from the cell and stores duration (minutes) into a vector 
  temp.tc[i] <- (as.numeric(unique(unlist(regmatches(dur, temp)))))
  n1 <- append(n1, i)
}

#checks if duration has units of hours
if((grepl(hr, dur) == TRUE) || (grepl(ho, dur) == TRUE))
{
  #removes words from the cell and stores duration (minutes) into a vector 
  temp.tc[i] <- (as.numeric(unique(unlist(regmatches(dur, temp)))))*60
  n2 <-i
}

#checks if duration has units of days 
if(grepl(day, dur) == TRUE)
{
  #removes words from the cell and stores duration (minutes) into a vector 
  temp.tc[i] <- (as.numeric(unique(unlist(regmatches(dur, temp)))))*24*60 
  n2 <-i #defines row where duration ends
}
}
}
```

I would really appreciate any tips on troubleshooting this!

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that `regmatches(dur, temp)` always returns something? The first thing I'd try is add `print(c(dur, temp)` and `print(regmatches(dur, temp))` to see what step causes the error.

Comment: Here is what I got: 

    print(c(dur, temp))
    [[1]]
[1] 8

[[2]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1

> print(regmatches(dur, temp))
[[1]]
character(0)